# PHP, POST, API - не могу подписать запрос в АПИ

Tags: php, api, post

Немогу понять, что я делаю не так в создании подписи.

Вот часть описания API:

```
access_key — публичная часть API-токена, которая отображается в кабинете в разделе API
tonce — временная метка в юникс-формате с миллисекундами
signature — подпись
```

Подпись генерируется по алгоритму HEX(HMAC-SHA256("HTTP-verb|URI|params", secret_key))

```
HTTP-verb — это GET или POST
URI — стока запроса без домена
params — отсортированные параметры, включая access_key и tonce, но без подписи
secret_key — секретная часть API-токена
```

Выставление ордера

```
POST https://SITE/api/v2/orders
```

Параметры:

```
side — buy или sell
volume — объём ордера 
market — btcuah
price — цена
```

===================================

Что делаю я.

```
    // Параметры
        $params = array(
          "access_key"=>KEY, 
          "market"=>"xrprub", 
          "price"=>"1",
          "side"=>"sell",
          "tonce"=>$time_server,   
          "volume"=>"1"
          );
        $params_encode = json_encode($params);

//генерирую подпись
    $xx=hash_hmac('sha256', 'POST|/api/v2/orders|'.$params_encode, $api_seckey);
$zzz=str_to_hex(hex_to_str($xx));

// обращаюсь через CURL
$ch = curl_init('https://SITE/api/v2/orders?access_key=KEY&tonce='.$time_server.'&signature='.$zzz);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$params_encode); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

"Signature is incorrect"  - что я не так делаю в подписи?

Comment: А где передача параметров?

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$params_encode);  там была другая переменная просто